# Jquery start search in self

Tags: jquery

I currently use the folowing:

```
var element = $('#Adiv').find('[name="thename"]');
```

This searches in Adiv for an element with the name 'thename'.
But Adiv could also have the name 'thename', so it should first look at its own name.
How do I do this? I tried `andSelf()`, but that just includes the entire element even if it doesn't have the right name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery find self](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312849/jquery-find-self)

Comment: Why not just use a better selector in the first place? See my solution below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18612523/357774

Answer (score 4):

you could do something like this:

```
var element = $('#Adiv').parent().find('[name="thename"]');
```

Comment: i don't know what the parent is, could be another div containing another element with the name 'thename'

Comment: how about $('div[name=thename').parent().find('[name=thename]');

Comment: this will fetch siblings of #Adiv and their childs too.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an option, as an ID is unique:

```
$('#Adiv').find('*[name="thename"]').add($('#Adiv[name="thename"]'));
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case, just change the selector and drop the `find`:

```
var $element = $('#Adiv[name="thename"], #Adiv [name="thename"]');
```

This will result in a jQuery object containing Adiv (if it matches), and any children of Adiv that match.

An alternative, more performant approach if you use jQuery >= 1.4 and know Adiv is definitely there in the DOM:

```
$('#Adiv').filter('[name="thename"]').add('[name="thename"]', window.Adiv);
```

...though I'd recommend the first one, as it's a bit cleaner and more resilient.