# jQuery find self

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

This may sound odd, but I'm working on a plugin that needs to find elements within a div, or the div itself.

The script finds an element based on a user selection, but the contents, including the markup is variable. So the script will look for the element as follows:

```
$('.block').find(selector); // selector set by user
```

but there isn't an easy way to have the selector select the '.block'. [Selecting the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689091/jquery-start-search-in-self) before using find isn't a solution, as there are multiple '.block' elements.

I know extending the `expr[":"]` selector won't work as it is only looking for children. But, I did figure out a way to "[duck punch](http://paulirish.com/2010/duck-punching-with-jquery/)" this method, by making a ':self' selector:

```
(function($){
    var orig = $.fn.find;

    $.fn.find = function(sel){
        return (sel === ':self') ? this : orig.call(this,sel);
    }

})(jQuery)
```

But this seems a bit over the top. And it will slow jQuery processing a tiny bit with every find function. Is there another way to do this?

---

Thanks for the answers! But I ended up doing this:

```
var b = $('.block'),
 el = (b.is(selector)) ? b : b.find(selector);
```

Comment: how about using `.add(this)` before the selector call. Without testing, would this add it to the list of "possible answers" that find can iterate?

Comment: @Brad I don't think `this` is defined in there. It was a nice thought though! but it did get me thinking about trying `.andSelf()` but that didn't work either =(

Comment: @fudgey: I would say you have the best solution then. The hook isn't that much over-head, all things considered, but I may recommend `return (this.is(sel) ? this : orig.call(this,sel));` A bit more intense, but won't restrict you to using ":self".

Comment: @Brad sorry I haven't had my caffeine yet, what does that do? I only wanted to add ":self" and shouldn't that be `$(this).is(sel)`? but it's still not registering how that is better?

Comment: @fudgey: say that you have a div, with the class "foo" applied (`<div class="foo"></div>`). And this element is stored as `el`. Traditionally, performing `$(el).find('.foo')` won't return the div, but only child elements with the class foo. By adding a `.is()` check, you can return the current element in the match, as el would in-fact have foo applied (e.g. `$(el).find('.foo') = el`). -- I didn't know if you wanted to stick with using ":self" or not, it just gives you the flexibility of using "Traditional jQuery selectors" and applying them to the currently-selected element.

Comment: @Brad Ahh ok, it'll just look for the selector. It does add two more function calls though... `$` and `is`, but add it as an answer and I'll accept it, thanks! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

approach with find('*') would be much more CPU intensive and I would recommend:

```
$('.block').find(selector).add($('.block').filter(selector));
```

Comment: +1 Thanks! but I think you meant `add()`. Anyway I actually ended up doing this: `var b = $('.block'), el = (b.is(selector)) ? b : b.find(selector);`

Comment: For a simpler, more performant generic solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18617975/357774

Answer (score 8):

I came across this problem too. I solved it like this (basically Romans Malinovskis solution as a jquery plugin):

```
$.fn.findAll = function(selector) {
    return this.find(selector).add(this.filter(selector));
};
```

Comment: I prefer this approach. It is elegant and I think it is faster than the '*' solution mentioned above, although I did not do any tests. I also think functionality like this should be in the jQuery core.

Answer (score 6):

**EDITED:**

You can use the all selector '*' combined with andSelf to get a selection containing an element with all its children and subchildren. Then you can filter() that selection on the chosen selector.

```
<style type="text/css">li {background-color: white;}</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  $('div').find('*').andSelf().filter(selector).css('background-color','blue');
}
</script>
<div>
This is a test
  <ul>
    <li class="test">This is a test</li>
    <li>This is a test</li>
    <li class="test">This is a test</li>
    <li>This is a test</li>
    <li class="test">This is a test</li>
    <li>This is a test</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Should change the backgrounds of all the .test objects, as well as the initial div that was selected, if it's appropriate. I'm not sure about the performance of my answer though.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7A9JJ/2/

**EDIT**
Or you could just do $('div, div *').filter(selector);

Comment: Since the user sets the selector `.test` (in your example), if it was replaced with just `li:first` then it would make the div as well as the first `li` blue, and this is not desired.

Comment: @fudgey Ah! I see. Give me a moment.

Comment: Nice... a bit convoluted, but it works nonetheless. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Since 1.8 you can do

```
$('.block').find(selector).addBack(selector);
```

Comment: Sorry, this won't work because if the selector finds the target, it should only return the target, not both the target and the `.block` which is what the `addBack()` does - see [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/cBAdg/).

Comment: @Mottie Duplicating the selector filter in `addBack` is important. Without that, it won't work. [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/cBAdg/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this needs to be so complicated. This can all be done with a simple [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
$(selector + '.block, .block ' + selector);
```

No `find`, `filter`, nor `add` to think about, plus it's [more performant](http://jsperf.com/jquery-compound-selector-vs-find/2) in many (most?) modern browsers (tested with jQuery 1.9).

**Caveats**:

- You may want to trim the user-supplied `selector` beforehand, since trailing spaces would have meaning here;
- This solution is somewhat specific to the OP's question and would not work if the target div's selector began with an element name, i.e. `selector + 'th, th ' + selector` would not yield a valid selector; in such cases I would recommend using one of the more generic solutions;
- You could still stick to the multiple-selector approach with an EXTREMELY HACKY, NOT AT ALL RECOMMENDED approach that involves using the `:not()` pseudoselector: [see working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LTeMy/2/) and [horrible, horrible performance](http://jsperf.com/jquery-compound-selector-vs-find/3).

Comment: it's a nice solution but since the user is providing the selector it could possibly be `'.block'`... so `'.block .block'` wouldn't work.

Comment: @Mottie, yes it would, actually: http://jsfiddle.net/LTeMy/ Did I misunderstand your concern?

Comment: In my case, I am using table headers so instead of `.block` I would need `th` and therefore the selector cannot also be `th` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LTeMy/1/)).

Comment: Ah, then that's a different question. :] I was answering the one where `selector` was the user input and `'.block'` was the selector for your target containing divs. The other answers are more generic/appropriate in the case where your own target selector begins with an element name, and I can update the answer to clarify this. Still -- just for fun! -- if you wanted to stick to the "single compound selector" approach you could use nested `:not()` pseudoselectors: [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LTeMy/2/) and [why you really shouldn't](http://jsperf.com/jquery-compound-selector-vs-find/3).

Answer (score 0):

I create jquery method findAll like below

```
$.fn.findAll = function ( selector ) {
    if ( this.length === 0 ) {
        return this;
    } else if ( this.length === 1 ) {
        return this.filter( selector ).add( this.find( selector ) );
    } else {
        var rtn = this.filter( selector );
        this.each( function () {
            rtn.add( $( this ).find( selector ) );
        } );
        return rtn;
    }
}
```

you can use it like below

```
$resultSet.findAll(selector)
```

Comment: You don't need the different this.length cases, especially the length > 1 look quite involved. Omnimike's implementation works correctly and probably efficient: http://jsfiddle.net/uKH9b/